# Intuitively, what is a Regular Boundary Point?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I'm taking an introductory level PDE class and for one lemma, we use the notion of regular boundary point, defined as follows:
$\xi \in \partial \Omega$ is regular iff $\exists p $ superharmonic on $\Omega$ s.t. $p>0$ on $\overline{\Omega} \backslash \xi$ and $p(\xi)=0$.

I don't really know what this means; I couldn't tell you which type of boundary point is or isn't regular.
I should also mention that if I'm not mistaken in this instance we use a generalized definition of a superharmonic funtion u which is that u satisfies $$ u(x)\leq \frac{1}{|\partial B_r(x)|}\int_{\partial B_r(x)} u(y) dS(y)$$ for all r small enough.

Edit: this is the definition for subharmonic, sorry

Comment: I know very little about this area (I'm only aware of it due to some overlap with porous set notions), but of possible use is the expository paper [*A necessary and sufficient condition of Wiener*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2305909) by Evans (1947) and this google search for [Lebesgue's spine](https://www.google.com/search?q=potential+%22Lebesgue%27s+spine%22&filter=0). Also [**Nonlinear Potential Theory of Degenerate Elliptic Equations**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486450503) by Heinonen/Kilpeläinen/Martio (1993; Dover reprint 2006) -- see in the vicinity of pp. 121-124 and pp. 171-178.

Comment: I think you've defined subharmonic?

Comment: True! I'm sorry

Comment: [This](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Barrier) might help you out (though it doesn't me).
"For instance, if $n\ge 3$ and $\xi$ is any boundary point for which there exists a closed ball $\bar{B}(R,y)$ in $D\cup\Gamma$ which meets $\Gamma$ only in $\xi$ ..."